# Job aborted due to stage failure on Magellan Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to make work the Magellan Package on Spark.
I am following the tutorial by harsha2010.

The repository is available at: https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan

I run this code on Spylon-kernel:

```
import magellan.Point
import magellan.Polygon
import spark.implicits._

case class PolygonRecord(polygon: Polygon)

val ring = Array(Point(1.0, 1.0), Point(1.0, -1.0),
 Point(-1.0, -1.0), Point(-1.0, 1.0),
 Point(1.0, 1.0))
val polygons = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    PolygonRecord(Polygon(Array(0), ring))
  )).toDF()

polygons.show()
```

I get the following error which is difficult to debug:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 16.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 43, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: PolygonRecord cannot be cast to PolygonRecord
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2861)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:637)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:596)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:605)
  ... 31 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: PolygonRecord cannot be cast to PolygonRecord
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  ... 1 more
```

Normally, the output should be:

```
+--------------------+
|             polygon|
+--------------------+
|Polygon(5, Vector...|
+--------------------+
```

Could you please help me fix the issue?

Thanks to you all!

Comment: Try to substitute the function: `toDF()` to `as[PolygonRecord]`

Comment: Thank you Thiago, but this is not working unfortunately